# Issue creating "custom" user URLs

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-routing

I am running into the following issue:

Our members have a desire for personalized sites directly from our primary domain in the form of `http://www.example.com/membername`. I am looking at possibly solutions in two ways but neither are ideal (will be explained below).

### Method 1 - `?Member=`

In this method, I simply create a custom URL and store the information in the member's database profile. For example: if I want my "custom" URL to be jm4, for a consumer to visit my site, they must type in `http://www.example.com?Member=jm4`.

The site, of course, does a `$_GET['Member']` to lookup the member information, stores the primary data in Session from the index page, then redirects to a homepage. The consumer no longer sees the membername in the URL but instead sees all the page names for www.example.com as if they simply visited the parent domain to start (each member's page has custom information however).

While this method works it presents the following problems:

- The URL is not nearly as easy as `/jm4`
  and any errors typing out the
  wildcard `?Members=` will result in
  page error. Also, This method keeps
  that particular member's information
  in session (which is necessary
  browing from page to page on that
  particular member domain) and
  prevents somebody from simply typing
  `http://www.example.com?Member=name2` to
  visit another site without clearing
  their session or closing the browser.

### Method 2 - `/membername`

While the preferred method, currently the only way we know how to create is to manually generate an index file in a subfolder, redirect to the primary index then allow the consumer to view the member's personal site.

For example, if I visit `www.example.com/jm4`, I am hitting the `/jm4` folder which contains *index.php*. Within this file simply contains:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

$_SESSION['AgentNumber'] = "779562";
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
?>
```

the primary index recognizes this with:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

if ($_SESSION['MemberNumber'] == NULL) {
     header("Location:ac/");
     exit;
}

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "USER", "PW");
mysql_select_db("DB",$conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE MemberNumber = $_SESSION[MemberNumber]";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
while ($newArray = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $_SESSION['MemberName'] = $newArray['MemberName'];
    $_SESSION['MemberPhone'] = $newArray['MemberPhone'];
    $_SESSION['MemberMobile'] = $newArray['MemberMobile'];
    $_SESSION['MemberFax'] = $newArray['MemberFax'];
    $_SESSION['MemberEmail'] = $newArray['MemberEmail'];
    $_SESSION['MemberAddress'] = $newArray['MemberAddress'];
    $_SESSION['MemberCity'] = $newArray['MemberCity'];
    $_SESSION['MemberState'] = $newArray['MemberState'];
    $_SESSION['MemberZip'] = $newArray['MemberZip'];
    $_SESSION['MemberAltName'] = $newArray['MemberAltName'];
}
mysql_close($conn);
header("Location: home/");
exit;
?>
```

We would certainly prefer to use the second method in terms of 'ease' for the member but keep running into the following issues:

1. We are forced to manually create a
   sub-folder and unique index.php file
   for each new member we onboard
2. While the above probably could be
   automated (when new member creates
   profile, automatically generate php
   file and folder) but this is more
   complicated and we don't want to
   have 3000 subfolders on the primary
   domain.

Has anybody run into similar issues? If so, how did you go about solving it? What would you recommend based on my details above? Any advice is appreciated.

Also - using as subdomain (`membername.example.com`) is not preferred because our current SSL does not allow for wildcards.

EDIT 1 - EXISTING .HTACCESS FILE
My existing .htaccess file on the site looks like this for reference:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?Member=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your prefered method by just adding some lines to the `.htaccess` in your root directory:

[This site should get you started](http://web-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/url_rewriting_via_htaccess)
Or [this one](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I think your answer is great but it does bring an issue. Let's assume I want www.domain.com/jm4 to actually route to www.domain.com?MemberID=93023893 where both the shortened URL jm4 and member ID of 93023893 are stored on the specific member's database row, I was unable to find any htaccess redirect commands including mysql lookups

Comment: There is no way to access a mysql database in your htaccess.  You'd need to have the rule rewrite to www.domain.com?Member=jm4, then use a php script to determine jm4's member id.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using apache, then you could use mod_rewrite to change urls like `http://host/membername` to `http://host/memberpage.php?name=membername`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this in a .htaccess file for your second method.  It will rewrite http://yoursite.com/membername to http://yoursite.com/?Member=membername

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /?Member=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: while I agree with your code above, I am running into a server error. I have added notes to my original post for my existing .htaccess file which may be causing conflicts?

Note: as a test, i replaced the htaccess file as a whole with your code and it did not carry the variable to the necessary page as expected.

Comment: the specific apache error I get according to my logs is:
[Mon Aug 23 13:42:45 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: the page now redirects to my 404 - does not exist page. Please see my edit above for changes made directly to my existing .htaccess